# Code doesn’t work when I store an array index as a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, vue.js, dry

I am using VueJS to display a list of groceries. Each grocery item can be incremented or decremented. I wrote the following function to decrement:

```js
deleteItem: function(index) {
  this.items[index].quantity -= 1;
  if (this.items[index].quantity < 0) {
    this.items[index].quantity = 0;
  };
}
```

I’m trying to make my code more DRY so I tried putting `this.items[index].quantity` in a variable. I was wondering why my code doesn’t work whenI do this:

```js
deleteItem: function(index) {
  var itemQuantity = this.items[index].quantity
  itemQuantity -= 1;
  if (this.items[index].quantity < 0) {
    this.items[index].quantity = 0;
  };
}
```

Comment: because it is not a reference

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're modifying a *value* instead of a *reference*.

Value types, such as numbers and booleans, are always copied. This means you lose the reference to where that value came from.

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  a: 1
};

var a = obj.a;
a += 1;
console.log(a); // changed
console.log(obj.a); // unchanged
```

What you could do instead is hold a reference to the *object* you're interested in since objects are always a reference.

```js
var items = [
  { quantity: 0 },
];

var item = items[0];
console.log('Initial state:', item.quantity);
item.quantity -= 1;
console.log('After the change:', item.quantity);
if (item.quantity < 0) {
  item.quantity = 0;
  console.log('After the correction:', item.quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass directly the item instead of index :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
   return {
     items: [ { name: 'Product 1', quantity: 15 },
           { name: 'Product 2', quantity: 2 },
            { name: 'Product 3', quantity: 12 } ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addQuantity: function( item, quantityToAdd ) {
     if( item.quantity + quantityToAdd < 0 ){
       item.quantity = 0;
      } else {
       item.quantity += quantityToAdd;
      }
    },
    increment: function( item ) {
     this.addQuantity( item, 1 );
    },
    decrement: function( item ) {
     this.addQuantity( item, -1 );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item">
    {{ item.name }} {{ item.quantity }}
    
    <button @click="decrement(item)" type="button">Decrement</button>
    <button @click="increment(item)" type="button">Increment</button>
  </div>

</div>
```